# RecyclerView in Android: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Span count should be at least 1. Provided 0

Tags: android, adapter

This is an odd one:
In my app, I have an activity, that inflates a recyclerview. This activity is called from many different activities in my app with different parameters, so that always the same recyclerview gets inflated, but with different content. Makes it very easy to adjust!

Anyway, this is how I start the recyclerview:

```
var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_RecyclerView));
activity2.PutExtra("galleryType", 0); // 0 neuste, 1 beste
activity2.PutExtra("picturesinarow", 1); // gridbilder
activity2.PutExtra("recyclerLayout", (int)RecyclerLayout.Profile_Singles); // unterschiedliche layouts
activity2.PutExtra("hasHeader", true);
activity2.PutExtra("thumbnails", false);
activity2.PutExtra("RecViewLayout", (int)RecyclerViewLayouts.Profile);
Activity_RecyclerView.gallery = false;
activity2.PutExtra("finalActivity", (int)RecviewHeader.Profile); // What Activity do we want to see?
StartActivity(activity2);
```

Many intents, that lead to the correct result.

Now, In within my recyclerview, there is a header with buttons on it. One button for instance recreates the activity and shows the images in the recyclerview in rows of 3 instead of rows of one. its a bit of a long code but this is how that looks:

```
internal void RecreateToCorrectActivity(RecReloadPictures sortedBy, int picsInRow, bool hasHeader, RecyclerViewLayouts correctActivity)
{
    // sorted by, pics in row, hasHeader, finalLayout
    switch ((int)sortedBy) // { Newest, Best, HallOfFame, ByTask }
    {
        case 0:
            galleryType = (int)RecReloadPictures.Newest;
            break;
        case 1:
            galleryType = (int)RecReloadPictures.Best;
            break;
        case 2:
            galleryType = (int)RecReloadPictures.HallOfFame;
            break;
        case 3:
            galleryType = (int)RecReloadPictures.ByTask;
            break;
        default:
            galleryType = (int)RecReloadPictures.Newest;
            break;
    }

    if (picsInRow != 1) // sind es mehr als zwei bilder pro reihe, dann thumbnails laden
    {
        thumbnails = true;
        gallery = true;
    }
    else
    {
        thumbnails = false;
        gallery = false;
    }

    switch ((int)correctActivity) // { TheBook, Profile, HOF, StartChallenge }
    {
        case 0:
            finalActivityToLoad = (int)RecviewHeader.TheBook;
            if (picsInRow == 1)
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.TheBook_Singles;
            else
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.General_Gallery;
            break;
        case 1:
            finalActivityToLoad = (int)RecviewHeader.Profile;
            if (picsInRow == 1)
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.Profile_Singles;
            else
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.General_Gallery;
            break;
        case 2:
            finalActivityToLoad = (int)RecviewHeader.HOF;
            recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.HOF_Singles;
            break;
        case 3:
            finalActivityToLoad = (int)RecviewHeader.StartChallenge;
            if (picsInRow == 1)
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.TheBook_Singles;
            else
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.General_Gallery;
            break;
        default:
            finalActivityToLoad = (int)RecviewHeader.TheBook;
            if (picsInRow == 1)
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.TheBook_Singles;
            else
                recyclerLayout = (int)RecyclerLayout.General_Gallery;
            break;
    }

    //ohne prüfung
    this.hasHeader = hasHeader;
    this.picturesinarow = picsInRow; // gridbilder
    boolRecreated = true;
    //this.username = strUsername;
    mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    this.Recreate();
}
```

So basically, I am simply reloading the activity that is already open but with different parameters. I then call:

```
mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
this.Recreate();
```

... and the activity reloads itself. And just when the loading is done and the recyclerview is now inflating the layout I am getting the above error and thats it. I have NO clue why this is happening. Especially since the recyclerview does work when called with said parameters, when they came as extras from another activity.

Can anyone help me out?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, changing all the variables to static fixed it!